# UWP Add a Tile option

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create an option for my uwp on tiles 
Like facebook app or like this app on this picture

[image]

Any ideas :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "Jump lists" and are available for desktop apps starting from W7. However UWP apps can use them from 10586 - November Update. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList) you can find the documentation for the `JumpList` class.